# SQL query to return collated results based upon two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table with the following columns:

```
Id,   ConnectionId,  File,      FileCreated
int,     int,       varchar,     DateTime
```

**Data Example**

Further, suppose it is filled with unsorted data like the following:

```
    1, 3, "a.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.008
    2, 1, "b.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.007
    3, 3, "c.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.009
    4, 3, "z.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.002
    5, 3, "h.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.003
    6, 2, "ba.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.004
    7, 3, "zy.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.005
    8, 1, "f.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.001
    9, 1, "cd.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.006
```

How might I query this data so that the dataset returns me :

1. one row for each of the connections
2. ordered in time ascending order

**Expected Results**

The result I'm looking for would be the following:

(**Note**: I'm putting these in groups so you can see that they are returned based upon ConnectionId first (like group by maybe) ).

```
8, 1, "f.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.001
4, 3, "z.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.002
6, 2, "ba.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.004

5, 3, "h.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.003
9, 1, "cd.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.006

7, 3, "zy.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.005
2, 1, "b.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.007

1, 3, "a.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.008
3, 3, "c.dat", 2018-05-16 13:53:40.009
```

Hopefully my example shows you that these are not strictly time-based and not strictly connectionId based either.  It is both.

Comment: I'm getting tripped up by your phrasing. Do you only want one row per connection? And does the connectionID uniquely identify a connection? (If not, definitely change that name). This doesn't match up with the expected result if so.

Comment: Yes, ConnectionId does uniquely identify the connection.  That's a foreign key to the table and there is more to this table in real solution, but was trying to keep it simple. I would like the end-result to look just like all the rows that come back in my result example. Meaning many rows but grouped by connectionid -- but my language still isn't great in explaining. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Id INT,ConnectionId INT,[File] VARCHAR(100),FileCreated DATETIME2);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (1, 3, 'a.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.008')
,(2, 1, 'b.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.007')
,(3, 3, 'c.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.009')
,(4, 3, 'z.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.002')
,(5, 3, 'h.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.003')
,(6, 2, 'ba.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.004')
,(7, 3, 'zy.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.005')
,(8, 1, 'f.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.001')
,(9, 1, 'cd.dat','2018-05-16T13:53:40.006');

SELECT *
FROM @mockup
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ConnectionId ORDER BY FileCreated)
        ,FileCreated;
```

Editing this great answer to add the result (and updated DateTime to DateTime2):
Amazing -- the result matches my expected results exactly.

```
Id  ConnectionId    File    FileCreated
8   1              f.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0010000
4   3              z.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0020000
6   2              ba.dat   2018-05-16 13:53:40.0040000
5   3              h.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0030000
9   1              cd.dat   2018-05-16 13:53:40.0060000
7   3              zy.dat   2018-05-16 13:53:40.0050000
2   1              b.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0070000
1   3              a.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0080000
3   3              c.dat    2018-05-16 13:53:40.0090000
```

Comment: Thank you, very good answer and helpful temp / mock table to help me actually try it.  You were just slightly later than other answer.

Comment: @raddevus True, because of the mock :-D

Comment: I edited your great answer to show the result.  And to add this question related to the result.   I notice that the FileCreated time is like the group by time or something.  It's not the actual FileCreated that is associated with the original row.  This won't really affect my solution but it is interesting.

Comment: @raddevus, funny observation! Change the `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2` and you will see the expected values. This is due to the granularity of `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()` in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by connectionId order by fileCreated),
         fileCreated;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I never would've found this answer because I did not know about row_number() over partition etc.  I'm going to break this down further to understand it, but this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.